# Why does my "include SwiftyDropbox" cause a build error for my iOS Xcode Swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dropbox, swiftydropbox

I added the DropBox SDK/API package to my existing Xcode Swift app project and get this build error:
"No such module 'SwiftyDropobx'"

However, the package is there in my Package Dependencies....

[image]

Comment: Is it in the "Link Binary with Libraries" in the Build Phases of the Target?

Comment: No, it was not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to TARGETS >> Build Phases >> Link Binary With Libraries
press (+)
select SwiftyDropbox
Add.

Link Binary With Libraries should now list it.

Build.